# Answers vote count font-size is not homogeneous

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[Searching for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer), I realized the accepted ones (green colored) have a vote count font-size slightly smaller:

[image]

Related code:

```
strong {
  font-size: 100%;
}
.vote-count-post {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.answered strong {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to ignore it... thank you...

Comment: I've never noticed this, but now I won't be able to stop noticing this. I hate you.

Comment: Why would you do this to us?

Comment: what font size use?

Comment: You're a monster.

Comment: Do you have tinnitus?  Cause that would be great if you could notice it.... perhaps I will throw in a little manual breathing as well.  Hell, just to make it even I will remind you of that random itch that showed up for no reason.  I wonder how you look when you walk, like specifically how your legs feel when you walk.  You also just lost the game too...

Comment: @Newd Oh, and by the way, you should remember to blink.

Comment: This question would be better with some red free hand circles. I almost didn't know what you were referring too without this crucial visual aid. That being said +1 for pointing this out (even if I can't unsee it.)

Comment: Can we get a magnified version of this to highlight the issue? And can somebody count the pixel difference in width and height between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! The fix is live on production :) (both 20px now!).